# Webpage loads only when mouse is moved

Tags: css, joomla, html

I'm having an issue where my webpage loads only when I move the mouse.

I've loaded a joomla template.It loads up on Mozilla Firefox without any issue, but in IE only when I move the mouse the page displays.

Can anyone advice where and what I need to check? Looking through the forums, I see that there is a mouse tracking event, or movement. But would like to know more information. Or if someone could help me get rid of it. It would be great

Thank you

Eric

Comment: What's your browser? Some browsers have been known to be the culprits?

Comment: Kinda like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/rWdDt/embedded/result/)? (Note, that only works in IE9.)

Comment: @Jared: Its almost the same thing. When I move it my template appears. Any idea how to get rid of that issue?

Comment: Not really. I haven't seen anything, so I could tell you explicitly why it was happening (other than something gone wrong or, possibly, you have some rogue code that's been injected into your files).

Comment: @EricDavid should be your browser's problem. Try switching to Google Chrome.