# Webpage blank in IE until mouse moved

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

This might just be the weirdest browser quirk I've seen in my career. When I load [the page](https://shop.treasureandbond.com/index.php?c) in Chrome, FF, etc it works fine. When I load it in IE 7-10, the page is completely blank, then I move my mouse one pixel, and it draws the entire page instantly.

It didn't do this when it was launched, but I don't have a good idea of when it started, so I'm not sure what changed to cause it.

After some testing I discovered that if I rename `js/jquery.js` (so that it can't load), the problem goes away. Then I renamed it back to the linked URL and the problem starts again. I was using jQuery 1.7.1, so I upgraded to 1.8.3, but that didn't change anything.

I can't find anything on Google, except [this unanswered SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445080/webpage-loads-only-when-mouse-is-moved), which may or may not be the same thing.

In IE9, The Developer Tools console only displays these warnings, which I don't think are relevant:

```
HTML1113: Document mode restart from IE9 Standards to IE7 Standards
SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles were not applied to :visted
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? I think even IE has a debug tool now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be the IE peekaboo bug.
Add "position:relative" or "zoom: 100%" to the css of offending div.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have helped. I'm not completely sure if it fixed it or not, but I'm not seeing the problem anymore. I've heard of the hasLayout bug before, but never seen it blank out an entire page. I thought it was supposed to have been fixed in IE7, too. Oh well.

Comment: IE11 seems to have the same issue. At least, this popped up for me in IE11 and your suggestion seems to fix the issue for me.